# MDN'S Example of Element.hasAttribute() code is confusing to understand, I would like clarity on its code snippet

Tags: javascript, html

To get clarity on what .hasAttribute means, i looked it up on MDN. The following code snippet they've provided as an example for its use case is confusing to me as its attribute "bar" isn't an html attribute, rather seemingly a value. Is it custom? I've never heard of creating your own custom attributes. Can someone explain this?

```
var result = element.hasAttribute(name);

var foo = document.getElementById("foo"); 
   if (foo.hasAttribute("bar")) { 
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with associated HTML to show how the attribute `bar` exists on the element.

```js
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
if (foo.hasAttribute("bar")) {
    console.log('Element has attribute "bar". Value is:', foo.getAttribute("bar"));
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" bar="random string">Div Element</div>
```

> Is it custom? I've never heard of creating your own custom attributes.

Yes, that would be a custom attribute. However, the standard for custom attributes would be to use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```
<div id="foo" data-bar="">div</div>
```

There are exceptions to this however as web components can have custom attributes defined that are not `data- attributes`. But web components are likely not what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You will often see "foo" and "bar" used as place holders in code snippets. Its just a little programmer joke.

the words "foo" and "bar" come from "foobar" or rather "fubar" which is a term used to describe something that is broken. It stands for "F*d Up Beyond All Recognition"

Basically in the example you have, replace "foo" with the id of the html element and "bar" with whatever html attribute you are checking for on that element.